# When to use AzureQueueSink

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am in the process of integrating an existing azure data factory project in my solution. While observing the data factory pipelines I saw that all the pipelines use `SqlSource` and the destination is `AzureQueueSink`.

The input datasets are
  1. on-prem table
  2. The output of a stored procedure

The output is an azure sql table.

Now I am confused as to when to use this `AzureQueueSink` I checked on google but I did not find any information regarding the use case for this.

Below is the sample pipeline activity.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://datafactories.schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-09-01/Microsoft.DataFactory.Pipeline.json",
  "name": "OnPremToAzureList",
  "properties": {
    "activities": [
      {
        "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
        "typeProperties": {
          "storedProcedureName": "dbo.TruncateStgTable",
          "storedProcedureParameters": { "TableName": "[dbo].[List]" }
        },
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "AzureSqlTableStart"
          }
        ],      
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "AzureSqlTableTruncate"
          }
        ],
        "scheduler": {
          "frequency": "Day",
          "interval": 1
        },
        "name": "SPTruncateStgTable"
      },    
      {
        "name": "CopyActivityList",
        "type": "Copy",
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "OnPremList"
          },
          {
            "name": "AzureSqlTableTruncate"
          }
        ],
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "AzureSqlTableList"
          }
        ],
        "typeProperties": {
          "source": {
            "type": "SqlSource",
            "sqlReaderQuery": "select * from dbo.List"
          },
          "sink": {
            "type": "AzureQueueSink",
            "writeBatchSize": 1000,
            "writeBatchTimeout": "00:30:00"
          }
        },
        "policy": {
          "concurrency": 1,
          "executionPriorityOrder": "OldestFirst",
          "retry": 1,
          "timeout": "01:00:00"
        },
        "scheduler": {
          "frequency": "Day",
          "interval": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not use AzureQueueSink as copy into Azure Queue has not been shipped and we don't have any plan to bring it back. It's leaked into our Sdk/Schema by mistake :)

This sink type now gives you undeterministic behavior which happens to be working but that behavior is not to last too long.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I had over 50 activities which used `AzureQueueSink`. I Have already rectified it.